# I want to create an animated image ( like i am making a plus sign by hand)

Tags: android, image, animation, button

I want to create an animated image ( like i am making a plus sign by hand) to be put on my android image button after i click it. How do I create such a animated image? and put it on button in android?

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you've tried or link to some sites showing your research?

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare 3 images for button states, and put it into `“resource/drawable”` folder.

   button_normal_green.png – <kbd>Default</kbd> image button.

   button_focused_orange.png – Display when button is <kbd>focused</kbd>, for example, when phone’s keypad is move (focus) on this button.

   button_pressed_yellow.png – Display when button is <kbd>pressed</kbd>.
2. Add Selector for different button states

   Now, create a new XML file in `“res/drawable/”` folder, in whatever name you want, in this case, we just give a name as `“new_button.xml“`. This file defined which button state is belong to which image.

   Now, you can refer to this button via this Id : `@drawable/new_button`.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
     android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
     android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
   </selector>
   ```
3. Add Button

   Open `“res/layout/main.xml”` file, add a normal button, and attach the background image to above `“new_button”` via <kbd>“android:background="@drawable/new_button”</kbd>

File : `res/layout/main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/new_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

As per you required information, you can set bunch of images with + sign and blank images in button with `Frameanimation` which you can call on <kbd>clickEvent</kbd> of <kbd>ImageButton</kbd>

```
  imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonid);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animate();
        }
    });

private void animate() {
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonid);
    imageButton.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.simple_animation);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView
            .getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
    frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);
}
```

File added: res\anim\simple_animation

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="selected" android:oneshot="false">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/monkey_1" android:duration="50" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/monkey_2" android:duration="50" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/monkey_3" android:duration="50" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/monkey_4" android:duration="50" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/monkey_5" android:duration="50" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/monkey_6" android:duration="50" />
  </animation-list>
```

Comment: Thanks this info is helpful, but my basic query is i want a gif kind of image/drawing, which will show as plus sign being created. How do i create such image/drawing, using bitmap or OpenGL or Photoshop? which file fomat?

Comment: @user2773642 : Have look on the modified code. Try to animate button with `FrameAnimation`.